# How can I detect that a device change as unplugged headphones from laptop - chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webrtc, microphone

I am using navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() to list the available devices for a call (implemented using webRTC).

I need to be able to detect when headphones are unpluged/pluged.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: [Wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/LbtxeLvw/), even without any experimental flags (in fact, I get 3 `devicechange` events when I expect one in Chrome, a bug). Does your mic show up in the enumerated list?

Comment: It's weird, in some computer it does show on the list, in other computers not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MediaDevices.ondevicechange and enable "Experimental Web Platform features" as seen on similar answered questions.

Answer (score 1):

If the currently used devices gets unplugged, the MediaStreamTrack's onended callback should fire. If that happens call enumerateDevices again.